# Scrapy and HTTPS problems

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

We're running Scrapy 0.24.4 through a pool of 100 proxies, and are having trouble scraping HTTPS links. We often receive the following exception: "Could not open CONNECT tunnel". I know this happens when Scrapy can't negotiate an HTTP CONNECT tunnel with our proxies, but I don't know why.

I can successfully crawl the exact same URLs via the same proxy pool using the .NET stack, just not with Scrapy. The environment is Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: sometimes replacing `https://` with `http://` will work

Comment: @AnD -- How can you accomplish this? I've tried several solutions offered on SO, and none have worked 100%. I added a downloader middleware and overrode the `process_request` method, and I also edited my spider directly, but to no avail. Do you have a fool-proof way to accomplish this?